# Media Player with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, mapping, audio-player

IM trying to create an audio player, with a master play and pause button, each song has its play and pause button but that can be override by the master play and pause.

```
       const playing = () => {
          if(isPlaying){
          setIsPlaying(false)
          masterPlay()
       }else{
          setIsPlaying(true)
          handlePlay()
        }  
      };

 const handlePlay = (song) =\> {
 setCurrentTrack(song);
  setIsPlaying(true);

 };
 const masterPlay = () => {
   handlePlay()
   setIsPlaying(true);
 console.log(isPlaying)

  }

      {!isPlaying ? (
       //if playing is false, play the audio
        <PlayArrowIcon onClick = {masterPlay} /\>
        ) : (
        //else pause the audio
        <PauseIcon onClick = {handlePause} /\>
    )}

      <button className="next_button" onClick={() => handlePrevious}>
        <SkipPreviousIcon />
      </button>

      <ul>
        {songs.map((song) => {
          return (
            <li key={song.id}>
              {song.track_name}
              <PlayArrowIcon onClick={() => handlePlay(song)} />
              <button onClick={() => handlePlaylist(song)}>
                create playlist
              </button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      {currentTrack && (
        <audio
          ref={audioRef}
          src={currentTrack.track_url}
          onPlay={playing}
          onPause={()=>handlePause}
          onEnded={handleEnded}
          onTimeUpdate={handleTimeUpdate}
          autoPlay={isPlaying}
        />
      )}
    </div>
```

`

I'm having difficulty passing the current track into the master play, without ,mapping the songs array how can I make the master play control the music

Comment: What does  master play/pause control?

Comment: just like Spotify, the master play/pause can control all the songs but works  with the individual play/pause, so when it can pause and play any song

Comment: Okay. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
const [currentTrack, setCurrentTrack] = useState(null);

const songs = useSongs() // 

const togglePlaying = () => {
  setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
}

 const handlePause = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setIsplaying(false);
 }

 const handlePlay = (song) => {
  setCurrentTrack(song);
  setIsPlaying(true);
 };
 
 const masterPlay = () => {
  // If current track is empty
  if(!currentTrack) {
    // Play the first track
    setCurrentTrack(songs[0])
    setIsPlaying(true);
  } else {
  // If not, toggle the current Track
    togglePlaying()
  }
 }
  
return <div>
      {!isPlaying ? (
       //if playing is false, play the audio
        <PlayArrowIcon onClick = {masterPlay} />
        ) : (
        //else pause the audio
        <PauseIcon onClick = {handlePause} />
    )}

      <button className="next_button" onClick={() => handlePrevious}>
        <SkipPreviousIcon />
      </button>

      <ul>
        {songs.map((song) => {
          return (
            <li key={song.id}>
              {song.track_name}
              <PlayArrowIcon onClick={() => handlePlay(song)} />
              <button onClick={() => handlePlaylist(song)}>
                create playlist
              </button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      {currentTrack && (
        <audio
          ref={audioRef}
          src={currentTrack.track_url}
          onPlay={playing}
          onPause={handlePause}
          onEnded={handleEnded}
          onTimeUpdate={handleTimeUpdate}
          autoPlay={isPlaying}
        />
      )}
    </div>
```